# Reference year sequence change

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, natbib, back-referencing

I am working with a report type document, with the settings of:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % omit 'round' option if you prefer square brackets
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength{\bibsep}{18pt}
```

So I get the reference list is:

```
Elisa S. DATA MINING. CRC Press, NewYourk, 2013.
```

What I want is:

```
  Elisa S.(2013) DATA MINING. NewYourk: CRC Press.
```

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  not relevant to the question, but the location of the publisher is "New York".

Comment: It is solved by write a totally new .bst file...so all the references goes the way you want

Answer (score 2):

There are several bibliography styles that might do what you want.  In your `\bibliographystyle` command, instead of `plainnat`, try `cj`, `decsci`, `apalike`, `jtb`, or `apasoft`.  Examples are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110717091346/http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.pdf).  If none of those works for you, take a look [here](http://www.blopig.com/blog/2013/02/how-to-make-a-custom-latex-bibliography-style/) for instructions on using the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) package to make a custom bibliography style.

Comment: yes. I checked what you refered here. My reason why I use plainnat is because I need to have (Author,year) format in text. and reference list in this format:                                                                                      Author’s surname, First name(s) or Initials (year of publication). Title of Publication.  Edition. Place of publication: Publisher. *number of pages. *notes. *ISBN

Comment: Since you know what you need, try the custom-bib and let us know how it works!

Comment: @user2307344 Any updates?